# push div block up if there is space?

Tags: javascript, css, calendar, alignment, autojump

Hora here, i think of a calender with entries over multiple days. if there are multiple entries overlapping they should automatically jump in one line if there is enough space. How could one achieve this? Is this possible with only little javascript?

A calender like this:
[calender image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpHlP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using div blocks to show a cell for every single day on your calendar. If you use `display: flex;` together with `flex-direction: column;` on your cells, you can determine the display order of its children (your entries) using the `order` property.

If you set a class with `order: 1;` on the entries that are part of a multi-day (overlapping) entry, those entries will be shown at the top of your cell.

You can read more about ordering flex items in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#The_order_property).